# eBay API FindItemsByProduct unable to return items available on a Fixed Price listing

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am trying to retrieve the number of items available on a Fixed Price listing using the eBay API findItemsByProduct, but could not find a property with the information.

Does anyone know if the available items count can be accessed by this call or is there another API I can use?

```
using (FindingServicePortTypeClient client = new FindingServicePortTypeClient())
{
  MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("My-CustomHeader", "http://www.mycustomheader.com","Custom Header");
  using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
  {
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
    HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();    
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-APPNAME", "INSERT APP ID");
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "findItemsByProduct");
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-GLOBAL-ID", "EBAY-US");
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
    FindItemsByProductRequest request = new FindItemsByProductRequest();
    ProductId id = new ProductId();
    request.productId = id;
    request.productId.type = "UPC";
    request.productId.Value = "783722722428";
    request.sortOrder = SortOrderType.PricePlusShippingLowest;

    FindItemsByProductResponse response = client.findItemsByProduct(request);

    foreach (var item in response.searchResult.item)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item.title); 
      Console.WriteLine("Item Condition:  " + Item.condition.conditionDisplayName);
      Console.WriteLine("Item ID:         " + item.itemId);
      Console.WriteLine("URL:             " +item.viewItemURL);
      Console.WriteLine("Listing Type:    " +  item.listingInfo.listingType);
      Console.WriteLine("Price:           " + item.sellingStatus.currentPrice.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("Shipping Type:   " + item.shippingInfo.shippingType);
      if  (item.shippingInfo.shippingServiceCost != null)
      { 
        Console.WriteLine("Shipping:      " + item.shippingInfo.shippingServiceCost.Value); }
        // Console.WriteLine(item.condition.conditionDisplayName);
        //Console.WriteLine(item.galleryPlusPictureURL);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
      }  // if
    }    // foreach
  }      // using
}        // using
```

Answer (score 0):

JMS

Ebay has one sdk for this in C# , is really helpful and easy to use.

https://go.developer.ebay.com/netsdk

For get your active products listed use the call [ActiveInventoryReport](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchant-data/CallRef/ActiveInventoryReport.html)

Comment: Looks like ActiveInventoryReport is not a standard call and probably only accessible by the owner of the store. I was hoping to be able to pull back the information using an API. I am trying to automate a report that show how my pricing compares to other sellers. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Hi, @JMS you mean use open find check if this suits  for you http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html#samplebasic , I've never used this function but ,  today at night I'm gonna create one lab for test after that I will send to you the feedback. In my company we have a list products listed in ebay we have managed just those products anyway.